# Two arrays or one in Map structure?

Tags: data-structures

I'm trying to create a Map where the data will be static and not change after the program starts (actually loaded from a server)

Is it better to have two arrays, e.g. in Java:

```
String keys[] = new String[10];
String values[] = new String[10];
```

where keys[i] corresponds to values[i]?

or to keep them in a single array, e.g.

```
String[][] map[] = new String[10][2];
where map[i][0] is the key and map[i][1] is the value?
```

Personally, the first makes more sense to me, but the second makes more sense to my partner. Is either better performance-wise? Easier to understand?

**Update**: I'm looking to do this in JavaScript where Map and KeyValuePairs don't exist

Comment: Is Java that language that you're going to be using for this?

Comment: Are you creating your own Map class, or are you allowed to use prebuilt ones?

Comment: Of the two, the first is clearer to me--and easier to get right! But the second approaches "KeyValuePair<String, String>[]" (array of key-value pairs)... which is clearer than both and probably the easiest to code correctly. But then why not use a Map<String, String> to begin with?

Comment: I'm looking to do this in JavaScript where Map and KeyValuePairs don't exist

Comment: any javascript object is a map: `var map = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2};`

Answer (score 4):

Using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementation (in Java) would make this easier to understand as the association is clearer:

```
static final Map<String, String> my_map;
static
{
    my_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // Populate.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) looks like what you need. It hashes the keys in such a way that lookup can happen in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

So, you're looking to do this in javascript. Any array or object in js in a map, so you could just do

```
var mymap = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'};
```